# Is there a better XML parser than XML::LibXML for Perl on Windows?

Tags: xml, windows, perl, libxml2

I have tried many of the Perl XML Parsers.  I was quite interested in the Sablotron Parser, but it is such a pain to install on a Windows box.  Currently I have started using [XML::LibXML](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-LibXML) and [XML::LibXSLT](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-LibXSLT) both of which seem to do everything I need.

They seem to be quite standard as well.  Are there any better XML Parsers to use than this?

Comment: The "best" XML parser is the one that meets your needs. You did not mention the type of XML parsing that you need: linear (SAX), tree (DOM), iterative (pull parser), etc so offering suggestions will be difficult.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think you are using a pretty good one.  [XML::LibXML](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-LibXML/), Matt Sergeant and Christian Glahn's Perl interface to Daniel Velliard's [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/) is one of the faster XML Parsers that I know of.

Comment: Thanks, just after clarification that I am using the right tool

Comment: Yea.  You definitely aren't using anything weird.. it is pretty close to standard.

Answer (score 12):

It really depends on your needs, as people have said. To parse XML files that were ~100Mb in size (gene annotations from [TAIR](ftp://ftp.arabidopsis.org/home/tair/Genes/TAIR8_genome_release/Tair8_XML/), 1 file per chromosome), I used mirod's [XML::Twig](http://xmltwig.org/) module, which lets you set callbacks to parse the elements that interest you, presenting each sub-document as an XML::Simple tree. It combines the benefits of a SAX parser (scanning the file as a stream) with a DOM parser (working more easily with the interesting pieces).

Answer (score 10):

If you need speed, power or features, XML::LibXML is the way to go.  If you're after ease of use, though, [XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Simple/) is a viable alternative.

Comment: Yes. Beware though: just because it's called Simple doesn't mean you're not supposed to read the documentation.

Comment: Indeed.  XML::Simple is probably one of the most featureful 'simple' parsing tools I've used in a long time.  :)

Answer (score 5):

In my experience [XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Simple/) is best for quick and dirty parsing of XML.  We use it for parsing data from third parties that do not always conform to the XML standard.  XML::Simple throws informative errors and gets you up an running extremely quickly.

Answer (score 5):

(Actually it's not an answer, but a comment - however, I cannot comment...)

XML::Simple has been mentioned here. 
(I know it's few from few years ago, but this appeared up in Google today...)

However, it's site (http://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple) now says:

STATUS OF THIS MODULE

The use of this module in new code is discouraged. Other modules are available which provide more straightforward and consistent interfaces. In particular, XML::LibXML is highly recommended.

The major problems with this module are the large number of options and the arbitrary ways in which these options interact - often with unexpected results.

Patches with bug fixes and documentation fixes are welcome, but new features are unlikely to be added.

Answer (score 2):

You could also look at [XML::Liberal](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Liberal/lib/XML/Liberal.pm) which uses LibXML underneath.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should give [XML::MyXML](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aMyXML) a try, too. It's very easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

I'll offer one that *SHOULD NOT* be used: [XML::Parser](http://search.cpan.org/~msergeant/XML-Parser-2.36/Parser.pm).

It automatically expands HTML entities to their UTF-8 equivalents, and the option to disable this behavior does not work on the most characteristic of all entities, `&amp;`.

Additionally, its XMLDecl-parser will interpret and display the `standalone` attribute in the `<?xml ... ?>` block as `"standalone"="1"`, which is absolutely incorrect -- it should be `"standalone"="yes"`.