# How can I remove external links from HTML using Perl?

Tags: html, perl

I am trying to remove external links from an HTML document but keep the anchors but I'm not having much luck. The following regex

```
$html =~ s/<a href=".+?\.htm">(.+?)<\/a>/$1/sig;
```

will match the beginning of an anchor tag and the end of an external link tag e.g.

```
<a HREF="#FN1" name="01">1</a>
some other html
<a href="155.htm">No. 155
</a> <!-- end tag not necessarily on the same line -->
```

so I end up with nothing instead of

```
<a HREF="#FN1" name="01">1</a>
some other html
```

It just so happens that all anchors have their href attribute in uppercase, so I know I can do a case sensitive match, but I don't want to rely on it always being the case in the future.

Is the something I can change so it only matches the one `a` tag?

Comment: Oh, how it hurts my brain whenever I see another "How do I uses regexes to parse HTML?" question. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-rege and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773340/can-you-provide-an-example-of-parsing-html-with-your-favorite-parser (and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487213/whats-the-best-xml-parser-for-perl in your case) before continuing with this.

Comment: In a general case, yes, regex isn't really designed for parsing XML/HTML. That said, if the problem space is limited it can be a viable option.

Comment: Also note that one of the biggest issues with attempting to use regex to parse XML/HTML is the fact that such generally requires recursive parsing; anchor tags are a convenient exception in that anchors are not allowed to be nested.

Comment: It is easy for this case - normally I would be voicing an objection about nested brackets, but none of the regexes given will be much affected by that. I will voice the "requirements change, and your regex may become unmaintainable as you try to adapt it to new requirements" objection, though, just for the sake of completeness.

Comment: This is turning into comp.lang.perl.misc. I'm sure we all want to show off our expertise, but could we consider the faint possibility that someone just needs a quick regex to do a one-off edit, rather than wanting to give us all an opportunity to show off our in-depth knowledge?

Comment: There is a great article by Mark Jason Dominus here: http://perl.plover.com/yak/12views/samples/notes.html

"Let's not forget the things that are good about Perl. It's good at interacting with other programs, and it's good for rapid prototyping. Let's not hassle people when they use Perl the way it was designed to be used."

Comment: @Kinopiko MJD is talking about invoking external programs via `system`: See http://perl.plover.com/yak/12views/samples/slide003.html

Comment: No, he is talking about this: "my complaint isn't so much about the position itself ... as with the dogmatism and thoughtlessness with which it's promulgated".

Comment: Dogmatism and thoughtlessness are all I see here.

Comment: @Kinopiko You cannot ignore what MJD's discussing. Plus, MJD is not defending a method that will give wrong results. Plus, I am in complete agreement with MJD on invoking external commands. Now, the people on this page who are objecting to parsing HTML with regexes, have made reasonable, thoughtful arguments showing you how easily that method fails. You happen to ignore all those arguments, claim this is dogma. Oh well. http://books.google.com/books?id=xHmlRamoszMC&lpg=PR3&dq=Reasoning%20About%20Knowledge&pg=PA49#v=onepage&q=&f=false

Comment: @Kinopiko, Cigarettes cause cancer.  Human activity has a major role in climate change.  Humans and apes share a common ancestor.  Many people claim that these facts are mere dogma. But it doesn't change the fact that they are true. Parsing HTML with regexes is a bad idea. Sometimes worse is better, but in this case relying on a regex is asking for trouble--oops, we had a link to a .php file, oops, here's a link to a .cgi, ad naseum--so the regex grows, ever more ungainly, and always broken. A real parser approach is easier to write (correct code), easier to maintain and easier to understand.

Comment: This kind of comment is exactly what I mean by dogmatism. For some reason you've decided that the above script is some kind of heavy duty HTML parser which needs to be maintained into the far-flung future and must be robust enough to process any possible kind of HTML input. Maybe it is, but maybe it is just a one-off which will never be used again. The dogmatism I am accusing you of is assuming the former and insisting on a full-blown solution which may be wildly inappropriate.

Answer (score 11):

Echoing Chris Lutz' comment, I hope the following shows that it is really straightforward to use a parser (especially if you want to be able to deal with input you have not yet seen such as `<a class="external" href="...">`) rather than putting together fragile solutions using `s///`.

If you are going to take the `s///` route, at least be honest, do depend on `href` attributes being all upper case instead of putting up an illusion of flexibility.

**Edit:** By popular demand ;-), here is the version using [HTML::TokeParser::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTML::TokeParser::Simple). See the edit history for the version using just [HTML::TokeParser](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTML::TokeParser).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;
use HTML::TokeParser::Simple;

my $parser = HTML::TokeParser::Simple->new(\*DATA);

while ( my $token = $parser->get_token ) {
    if ($token->is_start_tag('a')) {
        my $href = $token->get_attr('href');
        if (defined $href and $href !~ /^#/) {
            print $parser->get_trimmed_text('/a');
            $parser->get_token; # discard </a>
            next;
        }
    }
    print $token->as_is;
}

__DATA__
<a HREF="#FN1" name="01">1</a>
some other html
<a href="155.htm">No. 155
</a> <!-- end tag not necessarily on the same line -->
<a class="external" href="http://example.com">An example you
might not have considered</a>

<p>Maybe you did not consider <a
href="test.html">click here >>></a>
either</p>
```

Output:

```
C:\Temp> hjk
<a HREF="#FN1" name="01">1</a>
some other html
No. 155 <!-- end tag not necessarily on the same line -->
An example you might not have considered

<p>Maybe you did not consider click here >>>
either</p>
```

**NB:** The regex based solution you checked as ''correct'' breaks if the files that are linked to have the `.html` extension rather than `.htm`. Given that, I find your concern with not relying on the upper case `HREF` attributes unwarranted. **If you really want quick and dirty**, you should not bother with anything else and you **should** rely on the all caps `HREF` and be done with it. If, however, you want to ensure that your code works with a much larger variety of documents and for much longer, you should use a proper parser.

Comment: +1 for the example he might not have considered. That's what _should have been_ my argument against regexes in this case.

Comment: I don't see how this is straightforward. You have code which depends extensively on knowledge of Perl's reference system and there are several "magic numbers" in the code, with no explanation. Further, it relies on another module, and CPAN modules often lack clear documentation. Your solution is compact, but it is far from straightforward, unless one is a Perl expert.

Comment: @Kinopiko: 1. It's *correct*, unlike your solution, which breaks in any number of situations. 2. Code should be readable by someone who is *competent*. References are not a steep barrier to entry. A complete understanding of references is much easier for a beginner to come by than a complete understanding of regexes. 3. I would prefer `HTML::TokeParser::Simple` for its more readable interface, but if you can't spend a moment looking at the docs, once again, you fail it.

Comment: And 4. A module is used because once again *this is not a trivial problem*. If you treat it as a trivial problem you get a solution that is *wrong*, like the original poster's and like yours. A module suited to the task is almost guaranteed to be *less* buggy.

Comment: I agree that the magic numbers are confusing.  This is a property of HTML::TokeParser rather than the general "don't parse with regexes".  Using XML::LibXML's implementation of the W3C DOM would have been clearer, but more verbose.

Comment: My first instinct is usually HTML::TreeBuilder, but I appreciate the use of a streaming parser rather than DOM (or pseudo-DOM) where the problem allows. The other nice thing about TokeParser::Simple is that it makes round-tripping much easier :)

Comment: @jrockway On the other hand, the docs are very clear on what those numbers are http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTML::TokeParser::Simple#DESCRIPTION

Comment: "CPAN modules often lack clear documentation". And that's why you should never consider using a module if you can have a quick go with a regular expression? Wow!

Comment: Who care is CPAN modules often do anything? It only matters what the CPAN module you need does.

Answer (score 7):

A bit more like a SAX type parser is [`HTML::Parser`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML::Parser):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use English qw<$OS_ERROR>;
use HTML::Parser;
use List::Util qw<first>;

my $omitted;

sub tag_handler { 
    my ( $self, $tag_name, $text, $attr_hashref ) = @_;
    if ( $tag_name eq 'a' ) { 
        my $href = first {; defined } @$attr_hashref{ qw<href HREF> };
        $omitted = substr( $href, 0, 7 ) eq 'http://';
        return if $omitted;
    }
    print $text;
}

sub end_handler { 
    my $tag_name = shift;
    if ( $tag_name eq 'a' && $omitted ) { 
        $omitted = false;
        return;
    }
    print shift;
}

my $parser
    = HTML::Parser->new( api_version => 3
                       , default_h   => [ sub { print shift; }, 'text' ]
                       , start_h     => [ \&tag_handler, 'self,tagname,text,attr' ]
                       , end_h       => [ \&end_handler, 'tagname,text' ]
                       );
$parser->parse_file( $path_to_file ) or die $OS_ERROR;
```

Comment: +1 BTW, see http://www.perlfoundation.org/perl5/index.cgi?pbp_module_recommendation_commentary on `Smart::Comments`. I am not sure if I feel that strongly, but I am in general not a fan of source filters.

Comment: @Sinan Ünür: normally I remove debugging code from my finished answers. That's where Smart::Comments shines though, is debugging code.

Comment: That's not bad, but eventually does rely on another regular expression. However, HTML::Parser will give you attributes and their values if you ask nicely.

Comment: @Manni: Agree--and I knew that it did that, but I didn't want to write a complicated pipe when I was altering the tag--but it makes a better solution, if I'm not writing out anything. I'm going to change it.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another solution. I love [HTML::TreeBuilder](http://search.cpan.org/~petek/HTML-Tree-3.23/lib/HTML/Tree.pm) and family.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use HTML::TreeBuilder;

my $root = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_file(\*DATA);
foreach my $a ($root->find_by_tag_name('a')) {
    if ($a->attr('href') !~ /^#/) {
        $a->replace_with_content($a->as_text);
    }
}
print $root->as_HTML(undef, "\t");

__DATA__
<a HREF="#FN1" name="01">1</a>
some other html
<a href="155.htm">No. 155
</a> <!-- end tag not necessarily on the same line -->
<a class="external" href="http://example.com">An example you
might not have considered</a>

<p>Maybe you did not consider <a
href="test.html">click here >>></a>
either</p>
```

Comment: The documentation for TreeBuilder and friends could have been a bit more... _together_, but I agree, this is a very good way to work with HTML once you get used to it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just only remove links for which the href attribute doesn't begin with a pound sign? Something like this:

```
html =~ s/<a href="[^#][^"]*?">(.+?)<\/a>/$1/sig;
```

Comment: Doesn't handle bare links--I know, bare links are gross, and you'll never find them in HTML I write or write a generator for, but they and single-quoted attributes fit the spec.

Answer (score 0):

Even more simple, if you don't care about tag attributes:

```
$html =~ s/<a[^>]+>(.+?)<\/a>/$1/sig;
```