# How can I parse XML using Perl?

Tags: xml, perl

I have a file which has

```
<Doc>
<Text>
....
</Text>
</Doc>
<Doc>
<Text>
</Text>
</Doc>
```

How do I extract only the `<text>` elements, process them and then extract the next text element efficiently?

I do not know how many   I have in a file?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487213/whats-the-best-xml-parser-for-perl for another Perl xml parser answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/XML%3A%3ASimple) can do this easily:

```
## make sure that there is some kind of <root> tag
my $xml_string = "<root><Doc>...</Doc></root>";

my $xml = XML::Simple->new();
$data = $xml->XMLin($xml_string);

for my $text_node (@{ $data->{'Doc'} }) {
    print $text_node->{'Text'},"\n"; ## prints value of Text nodes
}
```

Comment: What if I didn't know how many <Doc> I had in a file, how would I use it? Thanks.

Comment: And I get a mismatched tag error...do you know what that means?

Comment: use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper($data);

Comment: @kunjaan: your xml is not valid. You can save it to file and open in IE for example to see if it's valid

Answer (score 8):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $t = XML::Twig->new(
    twig_roots  => {
        'Doc/Text' => \&print_n_purge,
});

$t->parse(\*DATA);

sub print_n_purge {
    my( $t, $elt)= @_;
    print $elt->text;
    $t->purge;
}

__DATA__
<xml>
<Doc>
<Text>
....
</Text>
</Doc>
<Doc>
<Text>
</Text>
</Doc>
</xml>
```