# How can I retrieve data between tags, in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm developing a perl script.

This is my input string in a file *new.txt*:

```
<ID>1</ID>
<CLASS>One</CLASS>
<NAME>Saran</NAME>
```

This is my code which simply prints the three lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
open(FILEHANDLE1,"new.txt") or die "Can't Open: $!\n";
while($line=<FILEHANDLE1>)
{ 
print "$line";
}
close FILEHANDLE1;
```

I need it to display only the contents between the tag. The
output should be:

```
1 One Saran
```

How should I retrive the data between tags?
Is there any way by using regular expressions?

Comment: A lot more explanation required in order to answer this question.

Comment: Do you just want to remove all of the tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What have you tried? What specific problems are you having?

It looks like you might want something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

$_ = 'Data1 some text Data2';

if (/Data1(.*)Data2/) {
  print "$1\n";
}
```

But your question is so vague that it's hard to be sure.

Answer (score 8):

[You cannot parse XML with regular expressions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

[You should use an XML parser instead.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487213/whats-the-best-xml-parser-for-perl)

Comment: I can't really see anything there that tells us the OP is actually trying to read XML. You're absolutely right if they are but who knows.

Comment: I think it's better to post a psychic ninja answer that turns out to be correct than to post no answer when you could have been helpful.

Comment: Possibly true - I was hoping he or she might respond to davorg's request for further info before responding.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Ether - this should be cast in stone. Or Adamantium. And perma-attached on top of SO.com :)

Answer (score 2):

If your input file is really as you described, you can do something like :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use warnings;
use strict;
open my $FILEHANDLE1, '<', "new.txt" 
     or die "Can't open file 'new.txt' for reading: $!";
while(my $line=<$FILEHANDLE1>) { 
    chomp $line;
    $line =~ s!^<(\w+)>(\w+)</\1>!$2 !;
    print $line;
}
print "\n";
close $FILEHANDLE1;
```

#### Always

```
use strict;
```

and

```
use warnings;
```

Use three args open and lexical handles.