# How to get opening and closing tags of xml in one line programmatically?

Tags: xml, perl, shell

I have a xml file as below:

```
<tr>
   <td>data1</td>
   <td>data2</td>
</tr>
```

I want to display the tr tags in one line:

```
<tr><td>data1</td><td>data2</td></tr>
```

Also I want this to work for every tr tag in the xml file.
Please help.

Edited the original question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best XML parser for Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487213/whats-the-best-xml-parser-for-perl)

Comment: how on Earth is this "not a real question"? It may not be terribly interesting, but a question it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with XML::Twig:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

XML::Twig->new( keep_spaces => 1,  # keep the original formating
                                   # but remove text in tr (ie whitespace)
                twig_handlers => { tr => sub { $_->cut_children( '#TEXT') } }
              )
         ->parse( \*DATA)
         ->print;

__DATA__
<html>
  <head><title>a title</title></head>
  <body>
    <h1>example data</h1>
    <table>
      <tr>
         <td>data1</td>
         <td>data2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>data1</td>
         <td>data2</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution somewhere between totally naive and real parser:

```
$xmlConetnts =~ s/\>\s*\n\s*\</></g;
```

This replaces `>  newline  <` with just `><`

Since XML does not permit `<` in the text data, you should be safe unless you have CDATA sections.

Comment: It would remove newlines everywhere though, not just between td's

Comment: true - modify it as needed, say replace `td>\n<td` and `tr>\n<td` and `td>\n</tr `

Comment: but then if a tr has attributes, your second regexp doesn't work any more. Oh, and no, `s{(tr[^>]*>)\s*\n\s*(<td)}{$1$2}` doesn't work either because you can have `>` in attribute values... and this way lies madness...

Comment: Indeed. This only works in very simple cases. May be good enough for one-off, certainly not for real world use.

Answer (score 0):

Simple: don't put new lines in your HTML/output.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but what about xml tags?

Comment: I mean what if I am working on an xml file which have custom tags?

Comment: Then, to follow this answer through to its logical conclusion: "Don't put new lines in your XML/output". That isn't very helpful though as this answer doesn't address the question "How can I programmatically remove new lines inside between pairs of start and end `<tr>` tags.?", which is what I interpret the original question as.

Comment: @Quentin: You are right!

Answer (score 0):

This problem is not as trivial as it might seem. A naive program to do this could look like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while ( my $line = <DATA> ) {
    if ( $line =~ /<tr>/ ) {
        while ( $line !~ /<\/tr>/ ) {
            chomp $line;
            $line =~ s/^\s+//;
            print $line;
            $line = <DATA>;
        }
        print "\n";
    }
    print $line;
}

__DATA__
<foo>
    foo
</foo>
<tr>
    <td>data1</td>
    <td>data2</td>
</tr>
<bar>
    bar
</bar>
```

But this only works as long as the file is formated in favor of the program and the tags in question are not nested. I suggest you look into an XML parser and write a custom pretty printer for that. A starting point could be to study the module `XML::Parser`