# Match everything except one char before a specific string in perl 5

Tags: regex, perl, xml-parsing

I want to match any block of text starting by this

```
<eu:img
```

followed by anything but

```
>
```

followed by

```
"<bean:message key="
```

followed by anything even a

```
>
```

For instance I want this text to be matched from ***eu:img*** to ***message key="***

```
<eu:img src="static/image/icons/erase12.png"
title="<bean:message key="attachedFile.delete.tooltip"/>"></eu:img>
```

But not this text :

```
<eu:img src="static/image/icons/erase12.png" title="someTitle"></eu:img>
<link title="<bean:message key="attachedFile.delete.tooltip"/>"></link>
```

Here is what I tried :

```
(?s)^<eu:img((?!.*?>).*.{1}?(\=\"<bean:message key\=\"))
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/EQyr_H-7SNhJR3eE)

Comment: Are you looking to capture anything after `<bean:message key=`? In your question you say: "`<bean:message key=` followed by anything, even a `>`, but then: "For instance I want this text to be matched from `eu:img` to `message key=`"

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse XML.  Use a proper XML parsing module.** You cannot reliably parse XML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the XML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken.  Start [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487213/whats-the-best-xml-parser-for-perl) for an SO question about which module to use, but also note that there are likely better more current lists on the Web.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
/(<eu:img[^>]+<bean:message key=)/gs
```

OP's EDIT : Good answer but not the right syntax for Regex engine I use : Eclipse (Perl 5 I think). This works fine anyway :

```
(?s)<eu:img[^>]+="<bean:message key="
```

- `<eu:img` matches the characters `<eu:img` literally (case sensitive)
- `[^>]+` match a single character not present in the list (`>`)
  Quantifier: Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
- `<bean:message key=` matches the characters `<bean:message key=` literally (case sensitive)

Comment: There may be corner cases where you'd need `<eu:img[^>].*<bean:message key=`