# Extract section of xml from result of curl command on Linux

Tags: xml, linux, perl, curl

I am issuing the following command:

```
curl http://localhost:8082/some-url
```

Which returns xml that looks similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><user><dateCreated>1</dateCreated><dateLastModified>1</dateLastModified><id>1</id><disabled>false</disabled><firstName></firstName><lastName></lastName></user>
```

What is the easiest way to extract an xml element from the response, e.g. the element "true"?

Note, I want the complete opening tag, content, and closing tag (and the content may also be empty.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487213/whats-the-best-xml-parser-for-perl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would xmllint be an option for you as well?

```
$ curl -s http://localhost:8082/some-url | xmllint --xpath '//user/disabled' -
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `xml_grep`, which comes with [XML::Twig](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML%3a%3aTwig), you can do `curl http://localhost:8082/some-url | xml_grep --nowrap disabled` (I assumed you wanted the content of the `disabled` element, I don't see any `true` element in your data)

Answer (score 0):

Or the same with `xsh` (http://xsh.sourceforge.net/):

```
$ curl -s http://localhost:8082/some-url | xsh -q -I - -C 'ls //user/disabled/text()'
```

Answer (score 0):

The classic solution is to use [`xmlstarlet`](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/), for [example](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html#idm47077139665568) for an RSS feed:

```
URL="https://feeds.feedburner.com/TEDenEspanol"
curl -s $URL | xmlstarlet sel -t -v 'rss/channel/title'
```